# React Redux - quick flash of previous state before dispatch issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a React + Redux app with a Node.js backend, and one of the features is that a user can view profiles of other users. To do this, I have a section in the `Redux state` called `users` that looks like:

```
{
    ...,
    users: {
        user: {},
        isLoading: true
    }
}
```

Every time the `/users/:id` route is rendered, a `getUser(id)` action is dispatched and fills the state with the received information.

The main issue is when a user views user1's profile page (therefore redux state is now filled with user1's profile) and then views user2's profile page, the dispatch `getUser(2)` action is called right after the page is rendered. Since user1's info is still in the state, it will flash their info for a very short time, and then show the loading spinner until the new user is loaded.

I read about dispatching a `resetUser(id)` action on every unmount of the page, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go. Also, one of the features is if a user is viewing their own page, they have an edit button which redirects them to `/edit-profile`. If I reset the state on every unmount, I'll have to fetch their profile again (in the edit page), even though I just did that when they viewed their page.. And that doesn't seem like it makes sense.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what approach you should take to avoid the flashing of previous data, but the edit page **_should absolutely_** fetch the data every single time it loads for numerous reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The `render` phase runs after `mounting`. And you stated that previous data is being shown before new data. It seems that you have asynchronous mounting:

```
async componentDidMount() {}
```

It will continue rendering even before mounting phase is completed. To avoid issue, you may use synchronous nature of mounting:

```
componentDidMount(){}
```

Where you'll call api data.

Now, when you reach to rendering phase it will have new data available before rendering and won't flash you old data.

---

You now may be wondering how to call api asynchronously. You can create a asynchronous function and call that function inside the synchronous componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
  yourAsyncFunc()
}
async yourAsyncFunc() {} // api call
```

> How can I do this with React hooks?

While using `useEffect`, don't implement async:

```
useEffect(async () =>
```

Implement it simply:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // you can still use asynchronous function here
  async function callApi() {}
  callApi()
}, []) // [] to run in similar to componentDidMount
```

If you miss second parameter to `useEffect` then you are not ensuring it to run on mounting phase. It will run before, after, and in the rendering phase depending on case.

Comment: How can I do this with React hooks?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing something like `resetUser(id)` seems to be the right way here. I use this approach in my current project and this does solve the problem. The other approach of removing `async` keyword from `useEffect` callback as mentioned in another answer didn't work for me (I use hooks, redux-toolkit, Typescript).

After dispatching this action, your state should look something like

```
{
  ...,
  users: {
    user: null,
    isLoading: false,
  }
}
```

If you are using hooks, you can dispatch the action this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ac = new AbortController();
  ...
  return () => {
    dispatch(resetUser(null));
    ac.abort();
  };
}, []);
```

Action could look something like this:

```
resetListingDetails(state, action) {
  // Immer-like mutable update
  state.users = {
    ...state.users,
    user: null,
  };
}
```